# Code cannot parse when return value directly in try catch block in a specific browser

Tags: javascript, browser, chromium, compatibility

I have a project that I need to test the compatibility of on a lot of browsers. Almost all of the browsers work fine, but I encounter code executing issues with a specific browser with user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0;
OPP R11 Plus Build/OPM1.171019.011;
wV) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Version/4.0
Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile
Safari/537.36 Mb2345Browser/15.6.2
```

When I try to run the following code inside an async function, the code never executes:

```
try {
    const jsonResult = await result.json();
    return jsonResult
} catch {
    return 'invalid json output';
}
```

However, if I change the code to

```
let jsonResult = 'invalid json output';
try {
    jsonResult = await result.json();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
return jsonResult;
```

then the code works fine.
Does anyone know why ==, I cannot debug because the browser disables the debug mode with Chrome.

Comment: Why are you not telling us _which_ browser fails? The big change between the two code blocks is the [optional `catch` binding (the missing `(e)`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_exception_identifier). Look at the browser compatibility table in the documentation. If you’re actually using a Chrome 62, that’s too old.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it is 2345Browser as mentioned in userAgent

Comment: @SebastianSimon aw probably it is due to optional change binding

Comment: Unrelated, but note that you can do just `return results.json()`. `async` functions return promises and returned promises are coalesced.

Comment: It could be due to the browser’s implementation of Javascript. A lot of browsers have their own implementation of Javascript, which can cause compatibility issues with certain code. It could also be due to the browser not supporting the return statement inside a try/catch block. This is something that is not supported in some browsers, so it could be causing the issue you are seeing.

Comment: The most likely thing is still the optional catch binding, so again: does it _work_ if you put an `(e)` after the `catch` in the first snippet? Does it work if `await` is removed?

Comment: @SebastianSimon it works after I put the catch (e) in first statement, it actually does nothing with the await statement

Answer (score 1):

Because, this is the correct way to write this code.

```js
async function getResult() {
  try {
    const jsonResult = await result.json();
    return jsonResult;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return 'invalid json output';
  }
}
```